# Spliting a long text string into predefined fixed length

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell, I am trying to figure out how can a long string be split in predefined fixed length variables:
For example below string is 30 characters long and I need to split in different fixed lengths like first 2 Chars, then 8 Chars, then 9 Chars then 1 Char then 5 Chars then 3 Chars then 2 Chars (total 30)
    $Inputlongtext= "123qwert5678990asdfghm09876564"
output that I need is:
    $out1 as 12
    $out2 as 3qwert56
    $out2 as 78990asdf
    $out2 as g
    $out2 as hm098
    $out2 as 765
    $out2 as 64
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings can be splitted with the SubString method:

```
.Substring( StartIndex [, length] )
```

e.g.

```
$out1 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(0,2)
$out2 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(3,8)
$out3 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(11,9)
```

Comment: Thanks Remko! This worked for me as follows: $Inputlongtext= "123qwert5678990asdfghm09876564"

$out1 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(0,2)
$out2 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(2,8)
$out3 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(10,9)
$out4 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(19,1)
$out5 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(20,5)
$out6 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(25,3)
$out7 = $Inputlongtext.SubString(28,2)

Write-Host $out1
Write-Host $out2
Write-Host $out3
Write-Host $out4
Write-Host $out5
Write-Host $out3
Write-Host $out6
Write-Host $out7

Answer (score 1):

*[edit - added missing `$Null =` to suppress the unwanted `True` from the `-match`.]*
*[edit 2 - added key sort to get objects back in source order.]*

here's a slightly weird way to do the job. [*grin*] it uses the regex `{count}` option to grab a specific number of matching characters. then it grabs the non-`0` keys from the automatic variable `$Matches` and looks up the values. finally, it sends the values to the `$Results` collection.

```
$LongText= "123qwert5678990asdfghm09876564"

$Null = $LongText -match '(?<P1>.{2})(?<P2>.{8})(?<P3>.{9})(?<P4>.{1})(?<P5>.{5})(?<P6>.{3})(?<P7>.{2})'
$Results = @($Matches.Keys.Where({$_ -ne 0}) |
    Sort-Object ).
    ForEach({$Matches[$_]})

$Results
```

output ...

```
12
3qwert56
78990asdf
g
hm098
765
64
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, this is indeed working but somehow the &result is not in right order as returning like : g
12
3qwert56
64
hm098
765
78990asdf Also it is also returning "True" on the top

Comment: ah! the `True` is coming from the `-match` - i will add the missing `$Null = ` that i left out. [*blush*] i need to find out what is munging the order ... i never noticed that sequence snafu ...

Comment: @M-ACharlotte - figured it out ...i forgot to suppress the `true` from the `-match` AND forgot that hashtables are NOT kept in order. [*blush*] so i added a key sort routine.

Comment: @M-ACharlotte - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]